# OpenCV Mat divide answers wrong

Tags: java, opencv

I have the following example code that calculates the percentage of red pixels,

```
import org.opencv.core.*;


public class ImageProcessing {
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Mat red = Mat.zeros(5, 1, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Mat sum = Mat.zeros(5, 1, CvType.CV_8UC1); // sum of red, green, and blue

        double[] red_data = {1, 1, 1, 1,255};
        double[] sum_data = {1,11,12,13,255};
        red.put(0, 0, red_data);

        sum.put(0, 0, sum_data);

        Mat percentage = Mat.zeros(5, 1, CvType.CV_64FC1);

        //red.convertTo(red, CvType.CV_64F);
        //sum.convertTo(sum, CvType.CV_64F);
        Core.divide(red, sum, percentage, CvType.CV_64FC1);



        System.out.println("Results");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d: %10f / %10f = %10f (%10f) \n", i+1, red.get(i, 0)[0],
                    sum.get(i, 0)[0],
                    percentage.get(i, 0)[0],
                    red.get(i, 0)[0]/sum.get(i, 0)[0] );

        }

    }
}
```

Running it I expect the results in ()s however I obviously get strange results. I thought at first it had to do with integer division ( see: [divide two matrices in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975420/divide-two-matrices-in-opencv) ). However converting them to 64bit floats (the commented out lines). Only gives other strange results.

Without float conversion

```
Results
1:   1.000000 /   1.000000 =   6.000000 (  1.000000) 
2:   1.000000 /  11.000000 =   1.000000 (  0.090909) 
3:   1.000000 /  12.000000 =   0.000000 (  0.083333) 
4:   1.000000 /  13.000000 =   0.000000 (  0.076923) 
5: 255.000000 / 255.000000 =   6.000000 (  1.000000) 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

With conversion to 64 bit floats

```
Results
1:   1.000000 /   1.000000 =   6.000000 (  1.000000) 
2:   1.000000 /  11.000000 =   0.545455 (  0.090909) 
3:   1.000000 /  12.000000 =   0.500000 (  0.083333) 
4:   1.000000 /  13.000000 =   0.461538 (  0.076923) 
5: 255.000000 / 255.000000 =   6.000000 (  1.000000)
```

I do notice there are consistent results where there is a clear mapping (1.0 maps to 6.0 for both 1.0 / 1.0 and 255 / 255 but I can't find a pattern that would cause this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are using [this](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html#divide(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double)) overload of the `divide` function:

```
public static void divide(Mat src1, Mat src2, Mat dst, double scale)
```

> Parameters:
>
> - src1 - First source array.
> - src2 - Second source array of the same size and type as src1.
> - dst - Destination array of the same size and type as src2.
> - scale - Scalar factor.

Which performs the operation `dst(I) = saturate(src1(I) * scale / src2(I))`.

**NB:** Note the actual meaning of the 4th parameter, where you pass `Core.CV_64FC1`.

With a little bit of research, you can find out that the value of the constant `CV_64FC1` is `6`.

This means that in reality, the calculations being performed are:

```
1 * 6 / 1
1 * 6 / 11
1 * 6 / 12
1 * 6 / 13
255 * 6 / 255
```

The rest is straightforward.

Note the requirement in documentation that the output array should be *"of the same size and type as src2."* In the first case, when the two input arrays are `CV_8UC1`, the second condition is not met, hence a new array is allocated.

Since in the first case the output is integer array, you see the [rounded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072053/opencv-round-after-division) results. In the second case it's floating point, so no rounding is done.

Comment: That was it, looking at the code I had mistaken the divide function for divide(double scale, Mat src2, Mat dst, int dtype)  and had missed the first argument being a double not another Mat. I did see that all the results were off by 1/6. Thanks.

Changing to core.divide(red, sum, percentage, 1, CvType.CV_64FC1); fixed it